# Shopify store custom file

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I want to add a custom file to my client's sites using a Shopify app.
eg. https://sohelamintest.myshopify.com/myfile.js
or https://sohelamintest.myshopify.com/apps/pushowl/sdks/service-worker.js

How can I do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Shopify's application proxies: https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies

They allow you to serve content for an assigned path on the shop's storefront.